# How to show the space is Frechet?

Tags: general-topology

The space $X$ is monolithic and $t(X)\le \omega$, then How to show $X$ is Frechet?

> $X$ is monolithic means that $\operatorname{nw}(\overline{A}) \le \kappa$ for any subset $A$ with the cardinality $\le \kappa$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too hard. Suppose $x$ is in the closure of $A$. Then there is a countable subset $B$ of $A$ such that $x$ is in the closure of $B$ (as $X$ has countable tightness). Now $\overline{B}$ has a countable network (as $X$ is ($\omega$)-monolithic). From this we should maybe get a sequence converging to $x$ from $B$...

**Added** This cannot be salvaged, as the counterexample by Brian shows. It does hold for compact Hausdorff monolithic spaces, as I say in the comments, because then $\overline{B}$ has a countable network and is also compact Hausdorff, and thus is metrizable. So a sequence as stated can then easily be found by first countability. Maybe Paul was working in compact spaces..

Comment: How do you know that it can’t happen that $x\in(\cl B)\setminus B$, and the only member of the countable network containing $x$ is $\{x\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you have a point. I'm so used to working in compact Hausdorff monolithic spaces, where we get automatic metrizability for the closure of countable sets. Here we just have a countable network. So we could indeed have an ultrafilter space ($\omega$ and a point at infinity that has the members (with the extra point added) of some fixed ultrafilter as its neighbourhoods and a network of singletons.. OK, another argument is needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: When $\overline{B}$ has a countable network, I just get the informationthat $\overline{B}$ is separable and lindelof. How could happen that there is a sequesce converging to $x$ from $B$?

Comment: @Paul We cannot. Only for compact spaces, as I said. The counterexample Brian and I mentioned (a countable ultrafilter space) works to give a countably tight, monolithic non Fréchet space.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$It’s not true. Let $p$ be a free ultrafilter on $\omega$, and let $X=\omega\cup\{p\}$ as a subspace of $\beta\omega$. $X$ is countable, so it certainly has countable tightness, and $\big\{\{x\}:x\in X\big\}$ is a countable network for $X$. Finally, $p\in\cl\omega$, but no sequence in $\omega$ converges to $p$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize my comment gave a counterexample right away... You're right of course!

Comment: @Henno: I just saw the word *ultrafilter*, and something clicked.